# Changed the name of the folder, now I can't open WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I wanted to change the name of the folder or the directory of my website. I had it like this: www.example.com/wordpress but then I changed the sub directory to another name and then I also changed it inside WP in Settings -> General. But then something happend and I can't access the admin of the website any more :(

Is there a way to change back inside some of the files? Help is preciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is well-documented on the official WordPress website:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Comment: Thanks! It worked! The site is up and running again! But how to I do if I want to change the name of the sub directory?

Comment: Hmm, it seems like a still have some problems! When I click on the items in the menu, I just get a 404-page!?

Comment: Which solution did you use? How do the links look like that give you a 404? I am going to need more details.

Comment: I used the functions.php file and uploaded it. I checked one more time and now they are working again! It was strange because when I hovered over the links in the menu, the link looked OK. Well, I'm glad it's working again, but I would like to know if it's possible to change the name of the sub directory the right way?

Comment: First you should change the URL within WordPress settings from `http://example.org/wordpress` to whatever you had in mind. Then you need to change the subfolder name in your FTP program. Remember that you can always use the WordPress documentation I linked to (should you encounter any errors when trying) and change back the settings by using update_option, or you could access the database and change the URL parameters from there.

Comment: OK, thanks for the help! I think the first setting I did was via the FTP and then inside WP. Perhaps that was the problem.

Comment: Just problems! I did as you wrote to try to change the name again, but then it didn't work! I tried to change back as I did before, but will not work at all now!? It's the menu that isn't working. Only the first item and when I click on the header image I get the index page, but not none of the other pages. I just get a 404 error asking for the path that didn't work.

Comment: The only thing that isn't working is the menu then. In a normal case, the hyperlinks in the menu should change URL:s when you use the provided solution. You can still access the WordPress admin panel, right? And you didn't hard code the menu links? You should check the permalinks settings in WordPress options for any clues.

Answer (score 0):

Since you first renamed the folder and then tried to change the site URL from Settings, WordPress never had a chance changing the option, since its requests would already result in a 404 Not found.

You can:

1. renamed you folder back to its original name, login, change the option to the new value, and then rename the folder to its new name. Or...
2. access your database using a tool such as phpMySQL, and in the `wp_options` table, find the rows where their `option_name` is `site_url` and `home`

Either one of these should do the trick.